# Async image loading in tableView using Parse.com and swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, asynchronous, parse-platform

I have an app like instagram that display photos in a tableView.
When the network is slow, image are re used in wrong cells and my dowload indicator label is also reused in wrong cells as i scroll fast.

I tried to use async image loading but can't optimize it.

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method :

```
      override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:WallTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as WallTableViewCell

    if indexPath.section == timeLineData.count - 1 {
        println("load more pics")
        loadPost()
    }

    cell.tag = indexPath.row


    // timeLineData is my data array

    if timeLineData.count != 0 {

        let userPost  = timeLineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as PFObject

        cell.commentButton.tag = indexPath.section

    // check if image is in the cache

     if let imagePostedCache: AnyObject = self.imageCache.objectForKey(userPost.objectId){

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? WallTableViewCell {
                cell.imagePosted.image = imagePostedCache as? UIImage
                cell.downloadProgressLabel.hidden = true
            }
        })

    }

        // if it is not in the cache get the image from Parse

    else if  let imagesPost:PFFile = userPost["imageFile"] as? PFFile  {
        cell.imagePosted.image = nil
        cell.downloadProgressLabel.hidden = false



        imagesPost.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData:NSData!, error :NSError!) -> Void in

            if !(error != nil) {

                let image:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!

                // add image to the cache

                self.imageCache.setObject( image , forKey: userPost.objectId)

                // display image in the cell

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                 if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? WallTableViewCell {
                        cell.imagePosted.image = image as UIImage
                    }
                })


            }

            else {
                println("error")
            }

            }, progressBlock: { (progressStatus :Int32) -> Void in

               cell.downloadProgressLabel.text = "\(progressStatus) %"

                if progressStatus == 100 {

                    cell.downloadProgressLabel.text = ""
                }
        })

        }

    // Define description

        if cell.tag == indexPath.row {

    cell.brandLabel.text = userPost["photoText"] as? String
        }
    }


    return cell
}
```

Here is my custom cell :

```
    import UIKit
  import QuartzCore

 class WallTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {



@IBOutlet var downloadProgressLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var commentButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var imagePosted: UIImageView!


@IBOutlet var brandLabel: UILabel!


}
```

Comment: You must create a custom cell to which you pass the url of the image of the PFObject in case of Parse and it will be the responsibility of the cell to download the image and show it. That cell will contain a UIImageView.

Comment: Ok, do you know a good tuto for this?

Comment: What is in your `WallTableViewCell`?

Comment: let me post you an answer. Give me a minute.

Comment: Just posted the answer.

Comment: Question : You seem to be managing the images manually.  Why not let Parse deal with the images download/position?  Have a look at this - the code is way simpler than what you have.  http://blog.bizzi-body.com/2015/02/13/how-to-display-parse-com-images-in-a-table-view/

Answer (score 1):

**WallTableViewCell**

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class WallTableViewCell: UITableViewCell 
{
    var isDownloadingInProgress
    @IBOutlet var downloadProgressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var commentButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var imagePosted: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var brandLabel: UILabel!

    func updateCellWithUserPost(userPost: PFObject)
    {
        if let imagePostedCache: AnyObject = self.imageCache.objectForKey(userPost.objectId)
        {
            self.imagePosted.image = imagePostedCache as? UIImage
            self.downloadProgressLabel.hidden = true
        }
        else if let imagesPost:PFFile = userPost["imageFile"] as? PFFile  
        {
            self.imagePosted.image = nil
            self.downloadProgressLabel.hidden = false
            isDownloadingInProgress = true

            imagesPost.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData:NSData!, error :NSError!) -> Void in
                isDownloadingInProgress = false
                if !(error != nil) 
                {
                    let image:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                    self.imageCache.setObject( image , forKey: userPost.objectId)
                    self.imagePosted.image = image as UIImage
                }
                else 
                {
                    println("Error while downloading image")
                }
            }, progressBlock: { (progressStatus :Int32) -> Void in
                    self.downloadProgressLabel.text = "\(progressStatus) %"
                    if progressStatus == 100 
                    {
                        cell.downloadProgressLabel.text = ""
                    }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath method**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    let cell:WallTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as WallTableViewCell
    let userPost  = timeLineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as PFObject
    if (!cell.isDownloadingInProgress)
        cell.updateCellWithUserPost(userPost)

    return cell
}
```

**Note:** I don't know Swift too much as I am a pure Objective-C programmer. Let me know if you have any questions regarding the answer

Comment: thanks for your help but it doesn't work. Image and dowload label are reused in a wrong cell...

Comment: it would be really helpful if you can share the code in order to solve the problem asap

Comment: All the wallTableViewController ?

Comment: Yes please if possible.

Comment: just try to move the "loading more pics" to the table footer. Because when you scroll it fast it will call again and again and that is what causing the problem I think

Comment: you should return `timeLineData.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `1` in `numberOfSectionsInTableView` The section should be 1 will all the photos as rows in that section.

Comment: I edit the post and added a check that if the downloading is already in progress then skip the downloading process again to initiate.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but for the UIImageView, I've had issues in the past where an image would duplicate in the wrong cell. I was able to fix this by using an if statement to explicitly define the image view with a placeholder image if it didn't have the new image yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SDWebImages . It will handle images for your application properly .

Comment: My problem isn't just an image reuse issue, i have to manage a label that display the download state. In the top of that, i m using parse.com as a backend. Parse take care of asynchronous downloading. What i have to deal for is the way cells are reused.

Comment: Before dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier , Check if tableviewcell is present or not .